# How do I return a different Promise only if first Promise errors out?

Tags: angular, angular-promise

The specific situation is:

- I'm using a local storage API that returns a promise when you try to 'get' the value.  The value I'm trying to get is a custom "UserProfile" object.
- If the value is not defined or is null, then I want to make an http call to get the UserProfile using a web request

Maybe I'm just not understanding Promises well enough.

Here's non-working code of what I want to do, but I don't know how the syntax works.

```
getUserProfile() {
  return this.storage.get("userProfile")
    .then(user => {
      if (user == null) {
        throw new Error("no user profile");
      }
    }
    )
    .catch(error => {
      //I don't know how to return a different promise
      return this.getUserProfileWithHttpCall();
    }
  );
}

//I want to return this in getUserProfile() if "userProfile" doesn't exist in "storage"
getUserProfileWithHttpCall(): Promise < UserProfile > {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/Account/GetUserInfo")
    .toPromise()
    .then(
    response => {
      this.storage.set("userProfile", response);
      return response;
    }
  );
}
```

`this.storage` is Storage from "@ionic/storage"

`this.http` is HttpClient '@angular/common/http'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your idea, there is no need to throw any error. You can do this:

```
getUserProfile() {
  return this.storage.get("userProfile")
    .then(user => user || this.getUserProfileWithHttpCall()
  );
}
```

Or in the `await`, `async` way:

```
async getUserProfile() {
  return (await this.storage.get("userProfile")) || this.getUserProfileWithHttpCall();
}
```

Maybe you want to rather use `Observables`, because they are the hip thing these days. you can change it to this:

```
getUserProfile() {
  return from(this.storage.get("userProfile")).pipe(
    concatMap((user) => user ? of(user) : this.getUserProfileWithHttpCall())
  );
}
```

You have to change your getUserProfileWithHttpCall then:

```
getUserProfileWithHttpCall(): Observable<UserProfile> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/Account/GetUserInfo`).pipe(
    tap((user:UserProfile) => this.storage.set("userProfile", user))
  )
}
```

Much neater :)

And finally, to explain why your method is not working, is because you are not returning the user in the `then` when it's not null, if you don't want to change your code so 'drastically', you can also just do this:

```
getUserProfile() {
  return this.storage.get("userProfile")
    .then(user => {
      if (user == null) {
        throw new Error("no user profile");
      }

      return user; // you missed this one
    }
    )
    .catch(error => {
      //I don't know how to return a different promise
      // Like you already did
      return this.getUserProfileWithHttpCall();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  Though it works now, I still don't understand why you can return "user || this.getUserProfileWithHttpCall()"  because `user` is of type `UserProfile`, but `this.getUserProfileWithHttpCall()` returns a `Promise<UserProfile>`

Comment: I wasn't able to get your 'Observable' solution to work - I think it should be `getUserProfileWithHttpCall(): Observable<UserProfile >` not `Promise<UserProfile>`  (otherwise, I was getting compile errors)


The compile error I get in the Observable solution of getUserProfile() is:
The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<UserProfile>'

This is more to satisfy my curiosity.  I'm going to stick with what I understand.  Though I really do appreciate you mentioning how it can be done with Observables

Comment: If you return a promise from a promise, any consecutive `then` will receive the value of the nested promise.. you can chain as many as you'd like, the end result will always be the last promise in the chain. And yes, I see I made some typos last night. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again, PierreDuc, for clarifying what happens when you return a promise in a promise